# In react native class component , cant not use setstate to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using this.setState to update state in my component, but something wrong with this, the callback of this.setState is also not executed.
here is my code:

```
{
            this.state.monthData.map((item, index) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.openMessage(item, index)}
                                style={[styles.calendarItem,
                                  this.state.activeIndex === index ? {
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderColor: 'red',
                                  } : {}]}
              >
                <Text style={styles.dayTitle}>{item.cDay}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.dayLunar}>{item.Term ?? item.IDayCn}</Text>
                <View style={styles.underline}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))

          }
```

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      monthData: [],
      offsetMargin: 0,
      activeIndex: null,
    }
  }
openMessage = (item, index) => {
    console.log('index', index) // output correctly
    this.setState({
     activeIndex: index
    }, function (){
      console.log('set success') // here is not executed
    })
```

#### what wrong with this?

Comment: try using arrow function.. `this.setState({
     activeIndex: index
    }, () => {
      console.log('set success') // here is not executed
    })`

Comment: I don't see any reason at all why the `setState` callback would ***not*** execute. Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue? You probably shouldn't use the `setState` callback anyway, instead log any state updates in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. It will be easier to reason about where in the component lifecycle you are when accessing the state value.

Comment: Sounds like you found the issue and resolved this on your own. I'm voting to close a unreproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way

```
openMessage = (item, index) => {
  console.log('index', index) // output correctly
  this.setState({
    activeIndex: index
  }, () => {
      console.log('set success') // here is not executed
});
```

Comment: thans for your help, finally, I found out that it was a third-party component that caused this problem